# how to find out what searched in google before entring my website?

Tags: search

As I mentioned I want to get what exactly searched on Google before clicking my website in google search results

My website is in php

Comment: thanx but in http_referer is just my website's url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the HTTP_REFERER [server variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to determine where the user came from:

```
$refererUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

You can also use a tool like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) which will perform the tracking for you.

Comment: I have test it but $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is just my website's url

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` will give the source page you came from just previous to the current page.  So that means if you have *any* redirecting, such as google -> http://mysite.com -> http://mysite.com/login, you will see your own site as the referer.  Try using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to track the sequence of steps leading up to your final website page.  Can you give the search terms used and the link to your website that you are using?

Comment: For example, google for "What is my referer?".  Then select the first link, which is a simple webpage that shows the value of `HTTP_REFERER`.  You will note that it contains a google url, such as `http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatismyreferer.com%2F&ei=fsszUL_6L4K2qQGgjoHQCA&usg=AFQjCNFt-KMqneTZfEb6OxjPZlD4ogiJcQ&sig2=CVS-hgk1dD3OKv-SFSoYiQ`.  However, as you can see in my example, the keywords may be stripped out if you're logged into Google.

Comment: When I go to "What is my referer?" from a browser where I'm *not* logged into Google, I get a referer containing the keywords as expected: `http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=what%20is%20my%20referer&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.whatismyreferer.com%2F&ei=TcwzUPewA-aNygG3wIGACQ&usg=AFQjCNFt-KMqneTZfEb6OxjPZlD4ogiJcQ`.  This could easily be captured into a database.

Comment: Oh it was my mistake.I forgot my auto ridirect.Thank you for your reply and information about fiddler.

Comment: you mean I cant catch what searched when user has logged in google?